# How do I resize a UIImage without smoothing?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uikit, core-graphics

I have a 16x16 UIImage. I want to convert that into a 128x128 UIImage without losing the sharpness. I will be putting the resulting image straight into a UIImageView.

These are the images start is on the left, then the bad image I get, then what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgZDo.png

How can I get from the image on the left to the image on the right?

Comment: if I had a picture of you in a PNG that's only available in 16 x 16, I'd have to likely to do a *lot* of Photoshopping to make a 128 x 128 version of that image that looks good.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann take a look at the photo. I want the result image to be blocky. The result should have 64 pixels of the exact same color for every one pixel in the original.

Comment: so your images are essentially bar codes?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann they are actually Minecraft texture files, but for the purpose of this question I want the same thing I would need from bar codes.

Comment: of course it will loose quality, because you are increasing dimensions/resolution of image from lower to upper, it will return wired output, if you decrease size then it will work properly.